Why is my super-capacitor self-discharging so fast?
I'm experimenting with a night light powered by a mini solar panel charging a super-capacitor instead of battery. (I know, I know. It's not recommended for this usage but I want to try it anyway). It works but the capacitor discharges too fast even before it is actually used. I tested the super-capacitor alone to see what is happening.
I have a 5.5V 4F super-capacitor very similar to the one in the image.

I charged it using a 18650 battery through a 5V step up converter for a couple of minutes. Then I disconnected it from power and connected it to a multimeter.  I turn it on and measure value during the day.
This is what I've got:

When I disconnect power, it drops immediately to about 4.5V, then rapidly discharges at the beginning. I read many articles about discharging.  It is hard to find info about this but according to what I learned it should drop about 10-20% per day. In this case it drops 1.6V (36% of charge, 29% of total capacity) in 8 hours.
I expected self-discharge but I don't understand why it is so fast. It does not help to add four parallel supercapacitors for a total of 16F.  The behaviour is similar. I need about 2.6V to run the circuit but it discharges even before it should do anything.


Is this discharge normal?
Is it possible that the capacitor is low-quality with high leakage?
Do I understand this topic correctly?
Did I miss any important info about super-capacitors?
Can you explain why this fast discharge is happening?


Update
Thanks for comments.

@Russell McMahon Exact product link is no longer available but it is probably this one Aliexpress GOHJMY V type 5.5V . I couldn't find datasheet for this, seems unbranded to me.
I found some branded expensive ones but they also have about 1000-1500 hours life, so about 5-8 years at 30°C. Is that too short?

@Gos I do what you suggest. Currently trying to "wake up" the cap by pumping 5V for hours. I am not sure if that's gonna work for long but let's try it.

@Tim Williams Thanks for exhausting answer. I like this kind of replies. I had to read it several times to get the idea. I think I get it mostly.
How do I understand
What I found about similar V-type coin cells they use to have purpose as "backup power supply" similar what you said. I understand that as these super-capacitors are exposed to power persistently during circuit operation and it's purpose it provide power when energy drops out. So they can have very-slow charging, pumping to every corner of capacitor under high impedance and then when needed, slow discharging provides long backup power supply. (Is that correct?)
About my cap
I tried to check ESR of the capacitor. I am not mistaken, it has about 350-450 Ω. (calculated by applying power and measure voltage with current). Pretty high I guess.
Searching for solution
I was looking for low-ESR types, it seems they have it about 0.1-0.6 Ω. I guess you were mentioning these "fast" ones right? Usually have fast charging and that I think is what I need. There is not enough sun during the day, I don't have eternity to charge it. I also found some "hybrid" types that should have high energy density similar to battery but durability of the capacitor. It seems these fast caps are not cheap but sounds like what I want so maybe I give it a shot.
Conclusion
I can say overall project was successful, cap nicely charge during the day and discharge during the night.
My project is not finished yet but I can close this one with solution. It seems capacitors I used are not suitable for application like I have. I replaced 4x 4F caps with 1x 100F (SECH C22S-3R0-0100) that has very low ESR (13 mΩ). I would interpret that as - able to charge and discharge much faster (don't accidentally bridge terminals, it will discharge in a second ... trust me ). Capacitor's voltage during day/night cycle ranges from about 2.2V to 2.65V. These are summer days, sun is strong but I think I can increase load for brighter led.

Details about solution. What changed:

Size. It's huge, not easy to fit under mini solar panel. It is similar to stacked 4x the old caps but 6x more capacity
Cap's voltage. Maximum voltage is now 3V. I need to use 3.3V step-up with diode to safely charge from panel. I also made protection using TL431 to be sure it never exceed 3V for safety
Output voltage. Discharging circuit drains capacitor using another 3.3V step-up. It increases and stabilises voltage of linearly dropping cap's power and effectively drains all power

Thank you @Tim Williams it helps me a lot.

The voltmeter was connected to cap all the time during measurement?

It would help if you described what exactly you bought and from where, and is there a data sheet for the exact component you bought. Otherwise everything might be normal for an unknown product bought from unknown origin.

Multimeter was connected to cap all the time but turned off. Turned on just for measurement.

Unfortunately this one is from Aliexpress and they provide too few info about that. So you say this can be normal for low quality components? That means I can find supercap that solves this problem?

We always suggest buying from reputable sellers (i.e. not aliexpress, ebay, or amazon) here. Especially with capacitors and batteries, you can frequently get something nowhere near the specs you paid for!

Charge and discharge it slowly more times, it should improve. I have similar supercaps, of 5F, and they work well.  One of them with a MCU that is most of the time in deepsleep, takes more than 24h to go from 5V down to 2.8V.

@Hearth  Commenting as an individual and not as an admin: This is NOT a complaint but an observation. I suggest that your "we" might better be "I" without more detail. I agree that the general message is correct, and that you didn't intend to provide a comprehensive comment on Asian purchases. In the past 6 months I have placed a very large number of orders with Aliexpress. This is because I have been prototyping and as my inquiry focus moves I want different items asap at acceptable prices. Results so far have been very good, with a few bad deals. None of this so far has been caps ...

... or batteries. I have some LTO and some Sodium-Ion cells on order "for interest".  Unlike most material which reaches NZ in under 2 weeks from order date, these are on a "slow boat" being batteries, so I won't know how good they are until July. || Back on topic :-) - I'd suggest something like "Buying from sellers such as .... can be a good choice if the items purchased are readily identified as being genuine. In the case of items such as .... it is far safer and often preferable to uy from ... ."

@Hearth 's advice often reflects reality. Components from low cost sources can be excellent BUT MAY NOT be. The lowest cost supercap from Digikey that approximately matches yours costs $US5 each in 120 quantity. (6F, 5.5V) . If you paid very much less than that  it MAY be an indication of  likely quality. || These 4F 5.5V are $US6.71 in 1's. You could consider buying one of these to provide a benchmark. || Note the size difference.

Can you please provide a link to the website that you bought those from. How much did they cost? I may buy some or similar to "play". I am currently prototyping solar powered lighting - including some at extremely low power levels. It would be interesting to see what results I got with sikiar "cheap" capacitors. || A possible issue is that such caps are often rated at 1000 or 2000 hours lifetime at 85 degrees C. Lifetime approximately doubles for each 10C drop So at 35C operation an 85 C cp lasts typically 2^((85-35)/10) = 32 times longer. So eg 32000 hours or about 4 years for a 1000hr cap.

Did the extended charge time change the discharge rate?

Not really, it behaves like before. Obviously higher voltage lasts longer but it drops significantly over time. Maybe it must be charged much longer, in days I guess, then it would also discharge slower. It seems these caps are not suitable for usage like this, they are probably just backup power like I described. I ordered different cap SECH C22S-3R0-0100 (100f) with much lower ESR 13mΩ. Currently I am testing it and it seems much better. Interesting is in comparison to my old caps, this one can be discharged extremely fast. I accidentally bridged pins for a second.

@eSeverus  Why are you using capacitors? I realise that there may be some potential (pun noticed) benefits, but there may be better ways of achieving the same aims, depending what the aims are. LTO batteries seem to have many of the advantages, are cheaper per capacity that SCs and appear to have potential lifetimes of 20 years +. I have some LTOs obtained from Aliexpress. (!!! :-) ). Yet to be tested.

Nice cap. What price? Where from? || I'm trialling LED lights at 150 uA :-) (At about 2.65 V Vf LED). 5 years x 10 hrs/day on 3 x GOOD AA. || A surprisingly useful amount of light.

Batteries are common solution, ofc I could do that. I read about many types of batteries and it seems they require a lot of care, constant and stable current, overcharge and undercharge protection, careful cycles for increasing lifetime, overheat protection, some even regular full discharge mechanism and so on. I see charm of caps they are simple, just protect voltage maximum. I can handle them with basic components instead of robust battery charger module. They should be more durable and do not contain reactive chemicals. I just target most effective solution from every perspective.

As I said, I have 2 of those coin supercapacitors of 5F from Aliexpress and they work perfectly fine. The discharge is linear. They are in a small weather station solar powered, and without any sun (or with the solar panel disconnected) they can survive about 3 days, going from 5V down to 2.8V when the MCU stop working. During the 3 days the discharge is almost linear. Maybe a bit faster when is above 5V, the 1st hour.  I monitor the voltage along with the temperature, humidity and so on.  With the solar panel (8x6 cms) it almost never goes below 4.7V.  I could show the graphs.

I can’t find coin supercapacitor 5.5V more than 4F. Are you sure you have the same type? Behaviour may depend on ESR of the cap. Do you have details to check the value or measure it?

https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005006377489880.html  https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005003638399312.html https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005005410657670.html

@Gos  using a Supercap looks interesting, but the advantages over eg a LiIon cell aren't obvious. 5F discharged from 5V to 1V gives about 15 mAh, and you are using a very small fraction of that. The cap is very costly - even from Ali express. A very small LiIon could be charged very conservatively and have many years of lifetime. OR 3 x eg Eneloop NimH would have vastly more capacity and cost no more. || As shown I estimate under 3 mAh. 3 x Eneloops charged would give about 600+ hours at that load. So -why use a supercap. NB - I'm not saying you shouldn't, but genuinely asking why do so.

@RussellMcMahon, yes, I agree. I did this just for experimentation and fun. I wanted to try to make it working directly with the WIFI to send the samples, that is more power hungry, and it works well. But supercaps in general have also some advantages; no over-charge/discharge control or problems, longer life and less maintenance, less problematic chemicals, resist better low temps.  They can be used also in hybrid system in front of a battery, to take over the frequent charge/discharge short cycles, or collect/deliver energy quickly. That's interesting.

@Gos I'm currently intending [tm] to get 5 years from 18650 LiIon in essentially unattended stations. Solar, Wireless links, lighting. Hundreds of nodes per location

You need to charge it for more than a few minutes.
The "self-discharge" curve you read, is also the charging curve (e.g. current flow for step voltage change).
These components have a diffusion characteristic, meaning the impedance varies as \$Z \propto \sqrt{\frac{1}{f}}\$, or similarly over time (hence the curve being fast at first, gradually slowing down; but not following a hyperbolic or exponential curve exactly).
In other capacitor types, this effect is small, and bears the name "dielectric absorption".  An aluminum electrolytic capacitor, suddenly discharged, might "recover" a few percent charge in some hours' time, but not usually anything dangerous.  In the double-layer capacitor, the dielectric itself (the ionic double layer) moves, migrating through myriad microscopic pores in an activated charcoal electrode; the ESR through any given pore can be almost arbitrarily high, so it takes a long time to charge up the most distant surfaces of the capacitor.  Meanwhile the nearby face, and the larger and shallow pores, charge up quickly, so you might deliver the bulk of current flow in a short time period, but charging (or discharging) current keeps on going for a long time after.  Slow and steady wins this race!
Typically, minimum leakage current is achieved after "soaking" for several days at given voltage.  Only then is leakage sensible in the usual way, for example (i.e. increasing exponentially as rated voltage is approached).
Since impedance changes so oddly with frequency, the capacitance also changes: at short durations (seconds to minutes), you may find it looks like a capacitor a fraction of the nominal value, with as much ESR (i.e., Xc = R, the characteristic of a pure diffusion (Warburg) element).  The rated capacitance is only reached at the given test frequency.  Ultimate capacitance, over the longest time scales (days to weeks), may even be higher than rated -- they just don't care to test the thing for so long!
Another way to put that is, the amount of capacitance, the active surface area, varies with frequency; the high ESR through narrow pores effectively blocks further area from being active at a given frequency.  Given more time, more surface is active, and the measured capacitance rises at low frequency.
This also means that a fast discharge is not very practical: the capacity is greatly reduced.  How fast, depends on efficiency/capacity requirements, and the type.  Low-ESR variants are available (e.g. Maxwell BOOSTCAP, having useful capacitance in the seconds to minutes range), but very slow types also exist.
Beware that, capacitors in this coin-cell style, may only be suitable for CMOS memory backup applications -- they typically have quite high ESR, in the kΩ.  Slow types.  Even for something like a solar night light, you may want a faster kind; check the datasheet to confirm.

Just a guess, Try checking the polarity of each capacitor. Even if 1 capacitor's polarity is wrong, it will discharge fast.
Edited - Try changing +ve and -ve terminal and see in which case the capacitor behave normally instead of discharging fast, if the problem was actually polarity.

Polarity was correct. Problem was elsewhere. Check updated conclusion for details. Thanks for effort anyway
